# what is a physical node in a blockchain network?

Tags: networking, blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin

If I want to create a website using blockchain, I will store blockchain data in a node, right? But what is a node?

Is a node a small server that I need to buy to run code and save data? 
Is a node a miner?
Is a node the client device like a laptop, phone, tablet that visits my website? 
A node is probably not the server that hosts the website

To sum up, what is a blockchain node? what is a blockchain network?

Answer (score 0):

"Node" refers to a running piece of client software. A client is an implementation of Ethereum that verifies all transactions in each block, keeping the network secure and the data accurate.

Becoming a Blockchain Node , means your participating in the Blockchain Network :>

There are 3 types of node

- Full Node ( Being a Miner )
- Light Node ( Useful for low capacity devices )
- Archive Node ( Quick Querying )

Resource

- https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/

Comment: Archive node is not just quick querying, but quick querying *in the past*.

Comment: Full node is **not** the same thing as a miner.